# Jetty chunked transfer encoding without keep-alive

Tags: asynchronous, jetty

I'm streaming data over HTTP using Jetty as a server. The data comes from a message queue, and I'm handling the processing asynchronously, printing messages to the connection when it is ready and there are messages available. When the client disconnects I stop consuming messages from the queue and clean up all resources dedicated to the stream.

Jetty chooses send the response chunked and sets `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` by default – this is what I want, since this is an endless stream and I obviously can't set a `Content-Length` header.

However, I also need to set `Connection: close` on the response. The server will run behind a load balancer that will try to keep a persistent connection to the backend servers, unless they explicitly send `Connection: close`. I have no way to configure the load balancer, it is completely out of my hands. If the load balancer keeps the connection open I have no way to know when to stop consuming from the message queue, because the connection will remain open.

The problem is that when I do `response.setHeader("Connection", "close")` Jetty stops rendering the response as chunked. It also does not set a `Content-Length` header, it just streams the output to the connection. As far as I understand this is not OK in HTTP, even though many clients probably will handle it. I would really like to use chunked transfer encoding, and also disable keep-alive. How can I convince Jetty of this?

Here is a minimal example that shows what I do. If I remove the line that sets the `Connection` header Jetty chunks the response, but with it it does not.

```
public class StreamingServer {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Server server = new Server(2000);
    server.setHandler(new AbstractHandler() {
      public void handle(String target, Request baseRequest, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {
        response.setBufferSize(1024);
        // if I remove this line I get Transfer-Encoding: chunked
        response.setHeader("Connection", "close");
        response.flushBuffer();
        AsyncContext asyncContext = request.startAsync();
        asyncContext.setTimeout(0);
        final ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();

        // start consuming messages from the message queue here

        out.setWriteListener(new WriteListener() {
          public void onError(Throwable t) {
            // stop consuming messages and clean up resources
          }

          public void onWritePossible() throws IOException {
            while (out.isReady()) {
              // send the next available message from the queue
              out.print(...);
            }
          }
        });
      }
    });
    server.start();
    server.join();
  }
}
```